# Mysql keep track of users views for each post in timelime

Tags: php, mysql

I have a screen that looks very much like facebook timeline

users can view posts of other users etc.

to get these posts i do something like

```
select user.id,user.name,posts.title,posts.body from posts left join users;
```

now data i need to collect is "Who saw this post" .

is there any elegant way to do it ?

right now all what i can think of is every time i fetch posts. i loop over them, then collect all ids of posts that the query returned and then push in another table

```
user_views [pk:user_id+postId]
userId,postId 
 1    , 1
```

Then when i'm fetching posts next time i can do `count` of `user_views`.

```
select *,count(user_views.id) from posts join user_views on post_id = post.id
```

but this sound like a lot of work for each `VIEW`, specially that most probably user will see a most multiple times,

is there any known patterns for such need ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a design question and the answer really depends on your needs.

If you want to know exactly who viewed what post and how many times, then you need to collect the data on user - post level.

However, you may decide that you do not really care who viewed which post how many times, you just want to know how many times a post was viewed. In this case you may only have a table with post id and view count fields and you just increment the view count every time a post is being viewed.

Obviously, you can apply a mixed approach and have a detailed user - post table (perhaps even with timestamp) **and** have an aggregate table with post id and view count fields. The detailed table can be used to analyse your user's behaviour in a greater detail, or present them a track of their own activities, while your aggretage table can be used to quickly fetch overall view counts for a post. The aggregate table can be updated by a trigger.